# Can I reuse the certificate of sponsorship after Tier 2 general visa refusal if the COS status is still "assigned"?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, uk-visa

I made an application for UK Tier 2 general visa as I had a valid CoS and other documents as well. I failed to provide UK NARIC report for proof of English language. So, the decision was refusal for Entry Clearance (UNDER paragraph 245HB(e)).

I have googled a little bit about reapplying with the same CoS. Seems like there are answers in the immigration boards which are too old. CoS still has "**ASSIGNED**" status and not **Withdrawn** either by Home office/Sponsor and my sponsor had amended the new joining date.

Can I re-apply for a visa using the same CoS? Can someone advice. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I had similar issues and it was mentioned in the decision letter that a new CoS is required if we are reapplying. Just saw this post and thought of replying. Have you managed to get the Tier 2 ?

Comment: Did u reapply with the same CoS? If the decision letter claims to apply with a new CoS please do so.